# Is there a way to tell the how close a shape is from being a circle?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I've recently done an experiment for one of my physics lab classes where I had to get the positions of an object moving on a path as close as possible to a circular one.

Given the path's graph I want to see how close this graph is from being a circle and I was wondering wether there is quantitative way of expressing this.

My specific graph is slightly eliptical and therefore it has $R_{max}$ and $R_{min}$ the maximum and minimum radiuses. My approach was to see how this two radiuses differ from the average and comment that on the lab report but I feel like there has to be a way of telling how close a given shape is from being circular.

Thanks for the help and sorry for any spelling or grammar mistakes as english is not my first language.

Comment: I think this can be likened to a "total error" or even standard deviation from statistics. Let's assume that you have a function in polar coordinates
$$
f(\theta) = R + r(\theta)\qquad \text{with}~ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi
$$
where $r(\theta)$ is small compared to the constant $R$. We want the average value of $r$ to be zero; $\int_0^{2\pi} r(\theta)\, d \theta = 0$. Now, how much would this differ from a circle? One could perhaps calculate something like
$$
\int_{0}^{2 \pi} (f(\theta) - R)^2\, d \theta
= \int_{0}^{2 \pi} r(\theta)^2 \, d \theta
$$
How does this look to you?

Comment: I'm not saying that would be a complete analysis, but it could be a starting idea.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roundness suggests a number of different ideas about how to compare a given set to a circle.

Comment: If your curve is genuinely an ellipse, then its *eccentricity* is a good measure of how far it is from  being a circle.

Comment: So, Mikel, would you like to engage with the comments?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not communicating.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't been able to answer, I've ended up using the eccentricity as the shape of the orbit I was analyzing was elyptical enough to make the assumption of it being a perfect elypse.

Comment: Still, I feel like @MattiP.'s idea was really good and before it was pointed out to use the eccentricity I was going to use that